# Setting up a Raspberry Pi with a Gertboard to use the Arduino Pins

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

This time its not a question in particullar. Its more a combination of questions. Im trying to setup a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a Gertboard, therefor Im using this Website (https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gertboard/arduino-ide-installation-isp/) as a guide. (Found no newer Information I can work with) Setting up the Raspberry with rasbian has worked without a problem. The upcoming problem is to install avrdude. 
The line:
`sudo dpkg -i avrdude_5.10-4_armhf.deb`

produces the following error:

(Reading database ... 103938 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack avrdude_5.10-4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking avrdude (1:5.10-4) over (1:5.10-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avrdude:
 avrdude depends on libncurses5 (>= 5.5-5~); however:
  Package libncurses5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package avrdude (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avrdude

To continue with the guide it is essential that this works.

Additional question: Finising the guid above is it possible to use the Gertboards Arduino Pins within a python code or is it necessary to write a code for the Arduino to write/read values and give them back to the python script?

Comment: Looks like you need to install `libncurses5` Maybe this will help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-install-ncurses-library-headers-on-debian-ubuntu-centos-fedora/

Comment: It worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see you passed through your issue, have you managed to initialize the gertboard and run a code with the arduino IDE?

We are currently trying to do it with a Raspberry Pi4B and it doesn't work. When runing the avrsetup we have this error:

```
avrsetup 

Initialising a new ATmega microcontroller for use with the Gertboard.

Make sure there is a new ATmega chip plugged in, and press
.. 1 for an ATmega328p or 2 for an ATmega168: 1
Initialising an ATmega328p ...
gpio/direction: No such file or directory
```

Have you got any issue like that?